# Magento importing product error

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, importerror

I am trying without luck on why this error is coming. Only import generates the error, export works well. I am using CSV file to import product data and can't get it to work. I have tried the same CSV in my local test Magento setup and it's working fine. Does anyone ever encountered this error?

[image]

On further investigation I found the DOCTYPE HTML code displayed is the HTML of Dashboard. It is loading Dashboard here. What can be the issue?

Comment: Did you try with a small subset of the CSV? I would say there is one or more lines are wrong. Find this line and you will find the error.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt OMG! You're a life saver! I am now able to import with 2 rows.

Comment: I got to know the error, I think now I will able to solve for rest of the data. Thanks man! Post it as an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: By the way, why are you using Dataflow instead of the new Import Export profiles?

Comment: @benmarks I'm using import/export dataflow profiles. I think the error I am encountering is because I already have products and running this for uploading images. I just checked in media/import few images are with extension `JPG` while all others with `jpg`. May be that caused problem in importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with a small subset of the CSV?

I would say there is one or more lines are wrong. Find this line and you will find the error.

Answer (score 5):

Adding another answer because this is what fixed the problem for me.
The `Number of records` option in the `Profile Wizard` tab should be set to a low number. I thought it meant the total number of records in the import but it means how many records it should process at once. 1 will always be safe but doing more at once will make the process faster. I set it to 100 and upped the php memory_limit to 1G and everything was fine.

Comment: I have that value to 3000 and that was my problem. Restoring it to 1 did the trick. Thanks @David Stone

Comment: Correct, the `Number of Records` entry is a chunking value. It determines how many records at a time (chunks/subset) get processed. Depending on the server and memory allocation, most people find it works at about 25-50. On a shared server, you may only be able to do 5-10 records at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You are encountering an error or a timeout during the above process. The error messages in Dataflow are *abysmal*, meaning that you either break up your input as Fabian suggested, or you drop some logging code to find the trouble data in [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product::parse()` (link)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php#L378):

```
public function parse()
{
    $batchModel = Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/batch');
    /* @var $batchModel Mage_Dataflow_Model_Batch */

    $batchImportModel = $batchModel->getBatchImportModel();
    $importIds = $batchImportModel->getIdCollection();

    foreach ($importIds as $importId) {
        //print '<pre>'.memory_get_usage().'</pre>';
        $batchImportModel->load($importId);
        $importData = $batchImportModel->getBatchData();
        /**
         * Temp debug code:
         */
        Mage::log(
            $importData['sku'],
            Zend_Log::DEBUG,
            'dataflow.log',    // find @ var/log/dataflow.log
            true               // force logging
        );
        $this->saveRow($importData);
    }
}
```

I would make sure that you have the records to import setting in the profile set to something reasonably low to keep each batch small.

Comment: Ok let me try this for 1200 rows.

Comment: I don't see `dataflow.log` created in var/log. It's really frustrating when we don't have SSH access to debug.

Comment: When I rename this method `parse` it throws error, when I log or print something it simply doesn't do. Strange. Thanks very much for your time @benmarks